# Pound(£) symbol replaced with some special character in struts FormFile

Tags: struts

Am uploading a file using struts `FormFile`, In uploaded file I specified pound(£) symbol and do uploading, but in the action server while reading the `FormFile` using `InputStream` or `Byte`, the pound symbol got replaced with some special character.

To resolve this issue, i made few changes in my jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

My action class:

```
final FormFile file = form.getUploadFile();
StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(file.getInputStream(), stringWriter);
final String data = stringWriter.toString();
final byte[] bytes = file.getFileData(); 
final String byteStr = new String(bytes,"UTF-8");
```

In both string fields  and , the pound symbol replaced with some special character.

Can any one please help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is getting replaced (i.e. it's not just your logger/debugger?) Have you written it to a file and then examined the file?

Comment: Also, are you sure the file you are uploading is encoded using UTF-8?